# How to sync files from two Operating Systems  to a same folder using U1?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have set up Ubuntu one on one Windows and one Ubuntu computer. I want to synchronize my files between the Windows and Ubuntu computer. Now I have two folders in the cloud. One Windows folder and one Ubuntu one folder. I would like to merge these folders such that both the Windows and Ubuntu computer both have the same files. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you add maybe your "documents" folder for syncing, which is inside your home folder, Ubuntu One should sync them between Ubuntu and Windows.

However, unfortunatly the Ubuntu one for Windows is english only, so if you do have a german Ubuntu installation, Ubuntu one will add a "docuemts" folder, and will not sync to the german "Dokumente" folder.